# typical memory usage of an iphone app

Tags: iphone

According to Instruments 'Net Bytes' of my app are never more than 2MB yet sometimes I receive memory warning and the app crashes because some views on the stack are unloaded by force.

I'd like to know what is the typical memory footprint where system would not send you memory warning and unload the views ?

I have so far tried this on OS 3.1.2 on iphone 3GS and 3G and with 3G giving warning almost 80% of the time I test the app on it.

Comment: Purely as advice, I would say your app needs to be able to handle memory warnings regardless of its size. If it isn't very big, maybe it doesn't have much ability to shrink its memory safely, but either way it shouldn't crash. Memory warnings are for every app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you're using to much memory. It might be some other application that's using the memory and causing your app to receive a memory warning.

The problem probably is that your not setting your views to nil on `viewDidUnload`.